# What resolutions can I use for the Raspberry PI camera 2? And how can you tell?

Tags: raspicam, opencv, c++

I'm working on a project with Raspberry Pi 3 and camera module v2.

I'm using OpenCV and [raspicam](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam).

I want to know the maximum resolution I can use. [The datasheet says 3280*2464](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/), but I get errors when using that resolution:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.ril.camera:out:1(BGR3): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.ril.camera:out:1(BGR3)(0x2022b60) (ENOSPC)
camera video callback2 erroropen Failed to create camera component/home/pi/repo/raspicam/src/private/private_impl.cpp 103
```

1920*1920 works fine, but I would like to know exactly how high my resolution can be before I get the error.

How can I debug the error message provided? And how can I know the the maximum resolution of the camera before I get the error message? (Please don't suggest trial-and-error)

Answer (score 2):

From [raspicam](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam#user-content-release-notes) , **Release notes**:

> Note: when using the full resolution video callbacks with the full
>   resolution of the Raspberry Pi Camera v2, you will likely get an error
>   such as mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port
>   vc.ril.camera:out:1(BGR3): ENOSPC. In order to fix this increase your
>   GPU memory to at least 256MB.

Comment: My question is regarding image in general, not necessarily video. Datasheet claims 3280*2464. I will try the trick with setting a too high resolution (your latest link) to make opencv automatically set the highest one, but I'm not entirely convinced it will work (since I get the error when it's too high).

Comment: @gromit190, please see my new edited answer.